# Examples in https://codelabs.developers.google.com/add-to-wallet-web don't work. JSON fails validation

Tags: google-wallet

I have been trying to generate a pass class using the codelabs example here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/add-to-wallet-web and keep getting a 400 error

{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "badRequest"
}
],
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
}

Is there any way to figure out what is wrong with the request? i.e. which part of the request is invalid. The body of the class follows the spec at:

https://developers.google.com/wallet/reference/rest/v1/genericclass

This is impossible to debug. Is there an example that actually works?

I tried using the code in the codelabs and I was expecting it to work.

Comment: Can you share the exact JSON you are sending.  If you have simply copy/pasted the example that you linked to, it won’t work.  Without knowing specifically what you are sending, it’s impossible to help you further.

Comment: I figured out the issue. I was trying to point to images using a file uri (file:///Users/zdayar/icon.png) and it seems this isn't supported. When I changed it to a file served from a web server it worked. Would have saved me a lot of time to know exactly what the 400 error was pointing to. Thanks